# how to keep position of other link when mouse is over a link-html Css?

Tags: html, list, hover, position, fixed

I have a ul list with float:right for li.
I want to set this to center of page.
margin and left doesnt work well.

I want when mouse is over a link ,keep position of other link and dont move forward.

My css code is this:

```css
#menu2 li a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu2 li a:hover {
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
}
<!--===============================================================<!--===============================================================--> --> ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #003;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu2 li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}
#menu2 {
  min-width: 800px;
  margin-top: 15%;
  right: 65% !important;
}
#menu2 li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #093;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  font-size: 18px;
  min-width: 95px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
  <div class="menu" id="menu2" align="center">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="brands.php">Brands</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      <li><a href="price.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Price List&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      <li><a href="index0.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this???
I use a:after but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing the li with div and write CSS style with the following attributes and change CSS Codes for div the problem was solved.
Thanks all

```
   <div align="center" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
              <div class="menu" id="menu2" align="center"   >
                                <div  style="z-index:18;position:absolute;margin-right:25px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" align="center" ><a href="brands.php">Brands</a></div>
                                <div style="z-index:17;position:absolute;margin-right:155px;"><a href="contact.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
                                <div style="z-index:16;position:absolute;margin-right:265px;"><a href="price.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Price List&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
                                <div style="z-index:15;position:absolute;margin-right:405px;"><a href="about.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
                                <div style="z-index:14;position:absolute;margin-right:520px;"><a href="index0.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

              </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added to your CSS, I Changed the hover text size to 25px and your button width to 135px and added in a whitespace:nowrap to the anchor tags.

what was happening is when you hover the text would grow and wrap because it could not fit into your containers, so i turned wrap off and also made the button containers width bigger to fit when enlarged

I hope this is what you are after as the buttons no longer move around the page when hovered on.

EDIT: Added CSS to your ul tag = float:left; so your buttons sit inside and achieve the dark blue background.

### CSS

```
#menu2 li a {

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
          transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
#menu2 li a:hover {

  border:none;
  font-size:25px; /*Changed by Steve */

}

<!-- ===============================================================
<!--=============================================================== -->
-->
ul,li
{
 display:inline-block;  
}
 #menu2 ul 
{

    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #003;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;

}


#menu2 li {

    float: left;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:15px 15px;




}
#menu2 
{
    min-width:800px;
    margin-top:15%;
    right:65% !important;
}

#menu2 li a {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#093;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    font-size:18px;
    min-width:95px;
    width:135px; /*CHANGED by Steve*/
    height:48.8px; 
    border-radius: 50px;
    white-space:nowrap; /*ADDED by Steve */

}
```

Comment: Thanks but didnt work.beacause mouse is over a link other link move a few pixel forward.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out whats going on here, there is something not quite right with the CSS, Generally to center something inside a div you can just set margin:auto. Sorry I couldnt help. It works good on my screen though. can you post what happens on imagur for others to see. Thanks.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/crwY4VZ/new - if the link still moves a few pixels still make the #menu2 li a width:145px;